# Ajax Devise update form only works if there are no form errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a devise form in which the user can change their password.  I did a custom redirect so it would go back to the edit password page after the form is submitted (instead of the devise default root page).  Here is the code for the custom redirect:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    protected

    def after_update_path_for(resource)
        puts 'redirect is happening' #This is so I can see it in the server logs
        flash[:notice] = "Account succesfully updated"
        edit_user_registration_path
    end
end
```

routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }
```

The only problem is that this will only do the redirect to the edit password page if changing the password is successful.  If not(lets say the user typed in the wrong password confirmation), it still redirects to the root page.  Does anyone know how to make this work properly when errors are present?

UPDATE:

It has something to do with the fact that i am submitting the form via ajax.  When the update is successful, the after_update_path_for method is triggered and the user is redirected to edit_user_registration_path which is configured to return javascript.  The problem is that if the after_update_path_For method is not triggered, it renders the edit_user_registration_path as it normally would with a failure, except it renders it as html, and I have made it so the page only renders via javascript.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The default RegistrationsController update method for Devise looks like this:

```
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    if update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
      yield resource if block_given?
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

The "else" is where your invalid redirect happens.  You could copy the method in your own RegistrationsController, and override the "respond_with resource" call with your call to your edit path. There's probably a more elegant solution but I'm not too good with AJAX yet. Maybe there's something for you to do with overriding Devise's respond_with method instead?